# Convert 4 binary bytes as single-precision float to Number

Tags: javascript, node.js, binary

I have a single-precision, big-endian floating point number stored in 4 binary bytes that I'd like to decode into a JS `Number`. The bytes were generated using Ruby's [Array#pack](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Array.html#method-i-pack) method like:

```ruby
[100.32].pack('g')  # "\x42\xC8\xA3\xD7"
```

Using the [npm `binary` package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/binary) I can decode these bytes as a 32-bit unsigned integer:

```javascript
let binary = require('binary');  // npm install binary
let buf = new Buffer([0x42,0xc8,0xa3,0xd7]);
let val = binary.parse(buf).word32bu('foo').vars.foo;
console.log(val);
// 1120445399
```

…but that doesn't help me. How can I convert either `1120445399` or `[0x42,0xc8,0xa3,0xd7]` into the floating point number `100.32`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like it's stored as a float, which is 32-bit. Node can already handle these common number parsing/writing scenarios. In this particular case, you can just use [`buf.readFloatBE(0)`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/buffer.html#buffer_buf_readfloatbe_offset_noassert) to convert the 4 bytes.